# mvc3 map routes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I am looking to use the following urls and maps some routes accordingly

```
<domain>/Home/About
<domain>/Home/SiteList
<domain>/Site/<id>/ (this one is defaulted to the details view)
<domain>/Site/<id>/section1/ (this one goes to section1 route in the Site controller)
<domain>/Site/<id>/section2/ (this one goes to section2 route in the Site controller)

e.g.
<domain>/Site/london/siteinfo
```

The above are covered by

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } //     Parameter defaults
        );
```

However, i also want to use the following routes

```
<domain>/Site/<siteid>/section1/controller/action (where controller gets data linked to the <siteid> and action is optional)
```

an example link would be:

```
<domain>/Site/london/siteinfo/manager (manager is a controller and will list managers for the site)
```

if have tried various routes and read various posts but could not find anything which was applicable to me.

Can anyone provide some help please?

Thanks
Rudy

Comment: Aren't your `{action}` and `{id}` switched?

Comment: Yes, i need it to be that way.  They will only see the 'details' action e.g. <domain>/site/london - Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add one more route below "Default":

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "MyRouteName",                                              // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{section}/{subsection}",                           // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id= "", section= "", subsection = "" }  // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Comment: I may be wrong here, but shouldn't any new routes be added ABOVE the default route?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i have updated the question, subsection should should have been the controller and added an example of a url